# INT 10h is not printing a character passed over stack

Tags: x86, nasm, bootloader

I am following instructions in a book. I'm trying to write a simple bootloader on an i8086 on QEMU.
I'm using the BIOS interrupt (INT 10,E - Write Text in Teletype Mode) to print out a character on a position I set before hand, also with a BIOS interrupt (INT 10,2 - Set Cursor Position).

Setting the cursor position works.

My goal is to make a subroutine "PutChar" that takes a char as a parameter and that then prints it. Printing the char directly (i.e. `mov al, 'c'`) works fine, which shows that it would actually work.

The register `AL` takes the character to be printed.
The register `AH` defines which function should be executed with INT 10h.

I put a star where the actual parameter should be copied to **AH**.

However, somewhere I'm making a mistake that I cannot find. I calculated again and again if I correctly referenced to 'A' on the stack, I even tried **[bp], [bp+8] and [bp+16]** just out of desperation so to speak.

Running these results in nothing being printed, not even a 'weird" ASCII character, which leads me to believe that there is nothing on the referenced address. Obviously I'm mistaken somewhere, but where?

Following code:

```
;********************
;A simple bootloader
;*******************
org 0x7c00
bits 16

start: 
  call MoveCursor
  push 'A' ; SP--, then put 'A' on stack. (8 bit only)
  call PutChar
  jmp boot


MoveCursor:
  mov bh, 0
  mov dh, 11
  mov dl, 10
  mov ah, 02h
  int 10h
  ret

PutChar:
  push bp ; SP--, SP--, then put Base Pointer on stack (16 bit)
  mov  bp, sp ;Copy Stack Pointer to Base Pointer
  *mov al, [bp+16] ;Since [bp] points to the old Base Pointer and the Base Pointer is 16 bits long, going back 16 bit would result in 'A', right?
  mov ah, 0eh
  int 10h
  pop bp 
  ret


boot:
  cli ;no interrupt
  cld ;all that we need to init
  hlt ;halt the system

;We have to be 512 bytes. Clear the rest of the bytes with 0
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Debugging time! Breakpoint in PutChar and check what content is pointed to by BP.

Comment: `[bp]` = old frame pointer, `[bp+02h]` = return address, `[bp+04h]` = your char.

Comment: holy guacamole, that helped. thanks! @m0skit0 bootloader is assembled in binary format, meaning (afai understood) there are no symbols that would let me set breakpoints at labels and such. But in the long run I surely would need to figure this one out.

Comment: @RnBandCrunk https://wiki.osdev.org/Kernel_Debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Margaret Bloom I solved it.
I actually **did** miscalculate, and I also didn't take into consideration that `[bp+8]` actually means 8 **bytes** after `bp` instead of **bits** as I intially just assumed. Thinking now, bytes is just logical - mistake on my part.

Then, I forgot that calling a function also adds to the stack: the return address of course.

So, in following order values get pushed onto the stack:

1. 'A' (8 bit, but since you can't push 8 bit on x86 16 bit get pushed in little endian format)
2. current IP (16 bit)
3. BP (16 bit) (<--SP is here now)

Then I save SP into BP and use BP to refer to my parameter 'A'.
As [BP] is my SP, [BP+2] would be my return address and finally [BP+4] is my parameter.

Note as I said, +2 means 2 bytes and not bit.

Comment: It's nice to see you solved your issue *and* posted and answer :) Bits are never addressable in x86 (though a few instructions deal with bits). Also, `push` pushes at least 16-bit (though the immediate operand con be 8-bit in the instruction encoding). Oh, you can accept your own answer. It's fine ;)